# Send Files over UDP Java

Tags: java, udp, datagram

I'm a stundent and this is a pre task Before a lab.

I'm trying to send files using UDP in java.

I've done it in tcp and got it working out of the box. Though i'm having problems with UDP.

The file is read, and sent in pieces of 1024 bytes. After that i'm trying to Catch them on the server side.

My thought at fist is that the for loop i'm using for counting in is to fast.

My output is a 56kb big file(346kb originally). The writeFile method gets entered once se client program gets a string (works), then when this method is run it'll keep on going in main loop to fetch other data. 
I seem to get more output in the console as thie method is done. (i'm Printing Everything using system.out.println)

It might be a question of speed, i've printed all 345 (353536/1024) files and tries that... it's sending. but not recieving.

Is there a way to "slow" the server down?

(i know UDP is nothing to rely on, but localy it should not lose data)

Client:

```
public void writeFile(String size, String fileName) {
    try {
        int test = 0;
        int totalSize = Integer.parseInt(size);
        BufferedOutputStream bOut = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
        for  (int i = 0; i < totalSize; i++) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
            datagramSocket.receive(packet);
            buffer = packet.getData();

            bOut.write(buffer);

            totalSize -= 1024;
            test++;
        }
        System.out.println(test);
        bOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Download failed, error occured!" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Server:

```
 if (msgFromClient.toLowerCase().contains("dload")) {
        File myFile = new File(msgFromClient.substring(6, msgFromClient.length() - 1)); // read file
        int totalSize = (int) myFile.length();
        byte[] buffer = ("ok:"+ myFile.getName() + "#" + Integer.toString(totalSize)).getBytes(); // send status + name + size
        udp.sendPacket(buffer);

        byte[] packageArray = new byte[1024]; // size of package to send

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));
        // send file in pieces
        for (int i = 0; i < totalSize; i++) {
            bis.read(packageArray, 0, packageArray.length); // read part of file into byte array
            udp.sendPacket(packageArray);
            totalSize -= packageArray.length; // reduce total size
        }

    } else {
        byte[] buffer = msgFromClient.getBytes();
        udp.sendPacket(buffer);
    }

}

private  void sendPacket(byte[] buffer) {
    try {
        DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        InetAddress receiverAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(
                buffer, buffer.length, receiverAddress, 81);
        datagramSocket.send(packet);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out this example.I used this for a school project also and it worked perfectly for me. http://www.coderpanda.com/java-socket-programming-transferring-file-using-udp/

Comment: The ordering of packets in UDP is not preserved. In other words the order in which you send the packets isnt necessarily the order in which they will be received. Also UDP packets arent even guaranteed to reach their destination. This can make UDP file transferes a bit more complicated. You will have to handle these possible cases.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Send Files using UDP in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33352881/how-to-send-files-using-udp-in-java)