# How to Send Files using UDP in Java

Tags: java, sockets, udp

i have a project in socket programming using java. We must write the Client and server Codes to transmit a file , The code shows no error at compiling but doesn't execute , it freezes when i put the name of the file .

I know that UDP is not a good idea for transmitting files but i have to do it as a project My codes are :

Client Code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Client
{
static InetAddress dest;
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception
{

    DatagramSocket clskt = new DatagramSocket();
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int port =input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Destination Host name");
    String hostname=input.next();
    dest.getByName(hostname);
    int packetcount=0;
    System.out.println("Enter The path of the file you want to send");
    String path = input.next(); 
    File initialFile = new File(path);
            FileInputStream targetStream = new FileInputStream(initialFile);
    int filesize=targetStream.available();
    //int neededpackets =(int)Math.ceil((double)(size/1024));
     byte [] data= new byte[1024];
     // counting bytes
     for (int i=0;i<1024;i++)
     {
         data[i]=(byte)targetStream.read();
     }
     //create a packet
    DatagramPacket clpkt=new DatagramPacket(data,data.length,dest,port);
    packetcount++;
    clskt.send(clpkt);
    if(packetcount >neededpackets)
        clskt.close();
   }

 }
```

Server Code

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.net.*;
 import java.util.*;

 class Server1
   {
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("Enter Port number !!!");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int SPort = input.nextInt();
    DatagramSocket srvskt = new DatagramSocket(SPort);
    byte[] data =new byte[1024];
    System.out.println("Enter a full file name to save data to it ?");
    String path = input.next();
    System.out.println("file : "+path+" will be created.");
    FileOutputStream  FOS = new FileOutputStream(path);
    DatagramPacket srvpkt = new DatagramPacket(data,1024);
    System.out.println("listening to Port: "+SPort);
    int Packetcounter=0;//packet counter
    while(true)
       {
           srvskt.receive(srvpkt);
           Packetcounter++;
           String words = new String(srvpkt.getData());
           InetAddress ip= srvpkt.getAddress();
           int port = srvpkt.getPort();
           System.out.println("Packet # :"+Packetcounter+"
            Received from Host / Port: "+ip+" / "+port);
           FOS.write(data);
           //out16.flush();
           if (Packetcounter >=100)
                 break;

      }
    FOS.close();//releasing file.
    System.out.println("Data has been written to the file !");
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for all.

Comment: Don't send files over UDP, there is no guarantee that your packets will arrive thus corrupting your files

Comment: i know that but i have to complete this code as a homework

Comment: Add `System.out` lines "everywhere" to see where the execution actually stops.

Comment: @kayaman that is terrible programming style, just use a debugger to step through your code

Comment: @kayaman it is pretty terrible, instructing new people with bad habbits is never a good idea

Comment: @kayaman OK sport...

Comment: alikh wer : You can find solutions to some of trivial problems in google. Have a look at : http://www.coderpanda.com/java-socket-programming-transferring-file-using-udp/

Comment: Not with this code. It is riddled with errors. You need to look at the Java I/O Tutorial, and the Custom Networking section too.

Comment: @Ravindrababu The code in your link is terrible too. It loads the entire file into memory at both ends, and it assumes that entire files can fit into a single datagram. This is rather unlikely to be true for the images that are used as examples, the maximum payload of datagrams being in practice limited to 1500 bytes or less. The article incorrectly states that the maximum is 64KB and then goes on to use a receive buffer of 50MB, which, given the maximum payload, is still a considerable waste of space.

Answer (score 2):

What I see at the first glance in the client is that the `dest` field that you try to use gets never unitialized, it remains null. You should write `dest = InetAddress.getByName(anArgument)` so that the `dest` get a value of a new InetAddress instance. So, most likely you'll get the Null pointer exception when your code gets compilable. Now it is not, as long as the `neededpackets` is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this helps you or someone in the future. I have created a UDP library to make UDP similar to TCP. This is a much more reliable form of transferring within UDP.

https://github.com/DrBrad/BetterUDPSocket

Heres an example for sending/receiving files within the library: https://github.com/DrBrad/BetterUDPSocket/blob/main/src/unet/uncentralized/betterudpsocket/Samples/FileTransfer.java

The way this can be achieved is by creating a new protocol. For example

```
+----+------+-------+------+
| ID | CODE | ORDER | DATA |
+----+------+-------+------+
```

In my library I used a UUID for the ID, this is a 16 byte identifier to ensure that packets don't get mixed up in streams. For example Lets say Alice wants to send 1.JPG as well as 2.JPG at the same time. We can't mix up these packets.

I created a few CODE's that may be helpful:

1. [0x00] DATA - Is for sending the data
2. [0x01] SUCCESS ACK - Is for when the data is received notify the sender that we have received the data
3. [0x02] FAIL ACK - The data is out of order, this will make the sender send the last packet
4. [0x03] KEEP ALIVE - Send a small packet every 25 seconds to keep your NAT from closing the port
5. [0x05] CLOSE - Tells the client/server that we have closed the connection

Finally for the ORDER
We have to make sure when sending a file that all the data is in order, It is very possible that when processing data the receiver may not get the last packet. This can cause the packets to be out of order. To counter this we have the client and the server count each packet sent/received successfully.

Comment: Have you ever benchmarked your library against just using standard TCP?  If the "protocol" is having the sender re-send packets how is that any better than just allowing TCP to handle the byte order? Seems to me that if you could send packets via udp, but have the receiving end buffer the packets into some kind of an array or a hash map where the re-assembly of the order happens as the packets are being received it might be much faster. Certainly will cost more in terms of memory use, but still faster in terms of bandwidth usage.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example I whipped up.  It uses `DatagramSocket` connections, which I think are the only way of doing it.

```
public class BroadcastTest
{
   private static final int RANDOM_PORT = 4444;

   public static void main( String[] args )
           throws Exception
   {
      InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName( "127.0.0.1" );
      DatagramSocket dsock = new DatagramSocket();
      byte[] send = "Hello World".getBytes( "UTF-8" );
      DatagramPacket data = new DatagramPacket( send, send.length, addr, RANDOM_PORT );
      dsock.send( data );
   }
}
```

Here's the server code.  These seem to work but I have not thoroughly tested them!

```
class Server {
   private static final int RANDOM_PORT = 4444;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         DatagramSocket dsock = new DatagramSocket( RANDOM_PORT );
         DatagramPacket data = new DatagramPacket( new byte[ 64*1024 ], 64*1024 );
         dsock.receive( data );
         System.out.println( new String( data.getData(), 0, 
                 data.getLength(), "UTF-8" ) );
      } catch( SocketException ex ) {
         Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName() ).
                 log( Level.SEVERE, null, ex );
      } catch( IOException ex ) {
         Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName() ).
                 log( Level.SEVERE, null, ex );
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: that is right but when i want to send a file we must talk about the size of the packet and this is my main problem

Comment: Just use `data.length` like you have, the same way I used `send.length`.  They are both just arrays.

Comment: you might have misunderstood me .what i am sending a file i need to convert the file into a stream i used what you are saying in my code but it doesn't help much i don't know what the problem is ..

Comment: Well if you can't define the problem we can't help you.  Datagrams/UDP don't deal with streams though.  Only discreet chunks of data like an array, just the way you have it now.